# VBA Create List to Loop ClearContents

Tags: vba, excel

I have an overly long block of code that I would like suggestions on how to clean up, because I clearly wrote it in the least efficient way.

Ideally, I am looking for suggestions on how to define the worksheets/ranges that clearcontents will run on as a list, then loop through each and run the script.

How might this best be accomplished?

I appreciate any help you might be able to provide.

```
Sub ClearContents()

    Sheets("Control1").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("Control2").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A8").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S1P1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S1P2").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S1P3").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S1P4").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S1P5").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S1P7").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S2P1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S2P4").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S2P8").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S3P1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S4P11").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S5P2").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S1P8").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S1P8").Select
    Range("G2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S5P10").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Sheets("S5P10").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a tip for next time you need code cleaned up or made more efficient (if/when); please post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Did not know that community existed. Will do, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ClearSomeSheets()
Dim ws as worksheet
For each ws in thisworkbook.worksheets
select case ws.name
case "Control1","Control2",
   ws.usedrange.clearcontents
case "Data"

    ws.Range(ws.Range("A8"), ws.Range("A8").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).ClearContents

case "S1P1","S1P8" 'etc....
   ws.Range(ws.Range("A2"), ws.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).ClearContents

end select
next ws
end sub
```

Comment: Harassed Dad, this is exactly what I was hoping to streamline the code to. Thank you so much or your guidance!

Comment: The reason that the amount of people asking for code or just to copy and paste a code increase, is that you provide the code without any explanation instead of provide guidance.

Answer (score 4):

I have some advice to improve your code:

1. Avoid using `.Select`. This will slow your macro.
   You can clear the contents using:

   ```
   Worksheets("S5P10").Range("L2").Clear
   ```
2. Use fully qualified names. Ex. `Worksheets("Sheet1")`
3. You can write a reusable procedure:

   ```
   Sub ClearContents(oSheet as String, oRange as String)
       Worksheets(oSheet).Range(oRange).Clear
   End Sub
   ```

Then, you can call your procedure using a `loop` with an array or just providing Sheet and Range

```
Call ClearContents("S5P10", "L2")
```

Comment: David, thank you so much for your input. This is a great suggestion that I will write into the code.

Comment: You can mark this answer as solve your question if you think it solve it! :) Glad to help you.